# How to view Swift API of AFNetworking?

Tags: objective-c, swift, afnetworking, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I am working on a Swift project using AFNetworking. I am using Cocoapods to manage my third-party Obj-C libraries and using bridge-header to import them in the Swift codes.

The problem is that I cannot use CMD+click to find the Swift API of those Obj-C classes (I am always led to Obj-C interface or implementation). I have to guess the format of API according to so-called Obj-C Swift Interaction and it is very annoying sometimes.

Is there any way I can directly check the Swift style API of existing Obj-C libraries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Alamofire when on swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Alamofire (swift version of AFNetworking)  : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: Thanks. I thought it is just another library at the very beginning.

Comment: The AF prefix in AFNetworking was just the short for Alamofire Networking